# Why does this recursive method cause a Stack Overflow error when it has no variables?

Tags: c#, multithreading, memory, stack, stack-overflow

I have recursive method like this, which doesn't contain any variable. Why is it throwing a stack overflow exception?

```
class MainClass
{
    static void Main() => Bark();

    static void Bark() { Bark(); }
}
```

in the example above, I did not create any variables. If I create any variable(either as a parameter or inside a method), then this is understandable: many variables have been created in the thread's stack, and due to the lack of memory, I get an error.

I don't understand, is the method itself is also stored on the stack? Why am I getting the error?

Comment: The **return address** is also stored on the stack. A method needs to know from where it was called to return to that code.

Comment: If I misunderstood, please correct me: You say that stack also storing addresses of methods?

Comment: not of the method, but of the code address where you want to resume execution when the called method returns.

Comment: Also the flags are also pushed.

Comment: Thank u all. @Jeroen van Langen can u please say what u mean about flags?

Comment: Your code is barking endlessly. You have introduced a recursion that has no base case.

Comment: @Gleb - Yes, that's the basis of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stack frame does not just contain parameters, it also contains a **return address**, so that the processor knows where to go back to.

Furthermore, the hidden `this` pointer is also a parameter. To remove that you would need a `static` function.

There is also the `ebp` or other stack-frame pointer, which can be pushed onto the stack for each call, depending on the exact calling convention.

So whatever you do, you *will* definitely get a stack overflow at some point, unless the compiler decides to perform tail-recursion.

Comment: thanks for answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you were to debug this piece of code and look at the "call stack" window then you would see it attempt to add `Bark` to the call stack an infinite amount of times because the recursion has no end point.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're expecting to see is tail recursion. Unfortunately C# compiler doesn't support it.

Comment: So, in your opinion, with tail call recursion elimination enabled, as I think you're referring to, should the compiler generate code that causes a stack overflow directly, or just an infinite loop?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Yes I think an infinite loop would happen. Instead of a memory error your program would just hang.

Comment: Yes i waited for infinite loop without any error. And thanks answer.